# How to nest an OnChange event in an OnLoad event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I'm working with Sharepoint and am creating a list with injected Javascript and JQuery. I'm trying to keep a field hidden unless the user selects "Deferred" or "Removed" from a field above with a dropdown. I want this to happen with an OnChange event, however, I believe this OnChange event should be within the OnLoad event.

Here's the code so far:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myFunction");
function myFunction(){
    $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Status Justification')".closest("tr").hide();

    var StatusVal = $('select[id*=Status]').val();

    if (StatusVal == 'Not Started' || StatusVal == 'Deferred'){
        $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Status Justification')".closest("tr").show();
        ---THIS SHOULD ONLY HAPPEN ONCHANGE FOR STATUS DROPDOWN---
    )
};
```

How can I use something like:

```
$('select'.on('change', function() {
            alert($(this).find(":selected").val());
        });
```

to make Status Justification only show when Status is changed to "deferred" or "removed"?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').on('change', function() { // whenever values are changed in dropdown, this will be called.
  if($(this).val() == 'deferred') { // example: run some code when value selected is 'deferred'
      // code goes here...
  }
});
```

And you need not have above code inside `$(document).ready(function(){` ..